# Trying to print 3 results into a table using re

Tags: python, regex, math, nltk

I've got a code that worked, up until I added the entropy portion to it.  Now it's giving me an invalid syntax error on the print line.  How come?

```
import nltk, math, re, numpy
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

def entropy(labels):
    freqdist = nltk.FreqDist(labels)
    probs = [freqdist.freq(1) for l in freqdist]
    return -sum(p * math.log(p,2) for p in probs)

def sents():
    fileObj = open('1865-Lincoln.txt', 'r')
    text = fileObj.read()
    tokens = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
    for name in tokens:
        words = ' '.join(name.split()[:4])
        count = len(name.split())
        entro = entropy(len(name.split())
        print('{:<35} {:^15} {:>15}'.format(words, count, entro))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a closing bracket missing in the line above:

```
entro = entropy(len(name.split()))
```

Comment: Holy crap.  I almost want to delete this now.  I can't believe I didn't see that.  Thanks for the eyes.

Comment: I actually went ahead and edited it, because something else came up when running it, but it's more of a math problem.